# Specific sequential numbering in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to create a spreadsheet with the following sequential numbering "0001/2014", I can create the number in reverse "2014/0001"  but that is not what I want. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: What sequence you're actually talking about? A sequence that runs from "0001/2014" to "9999/2014" or what? You need to clarify your question to make it possible to offer any meaningful advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXT(ROWS($A$1:A1),"0000")&"/2014"
```

copy down.

Comment: You could mark this as the answer, then, right? So others will find it too.